# Previewing File Geodatabase in QGIS Browser - Is it Possible?

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase-api, qgis-browser

Can I Preview/look at file geodatabase attributes in the QGIS browser if I have installed QGIS using OSGEO4W installer and FileGDB API? Currently I can add/edit file geodatabase feature classes to QGIS desktop, but the browser does not allow me to see preview/attributes/metadata. All I get is the Param tab previewing all the indexes, tables, yadda, yadda.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 2):

Not at the moment.

It's a requested feature, but unplanned.

See this bug/feature request: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/5814